# Wave texture shows in Material viewport, but not in Rendered view

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, node-editor

The only UV map is unwrapped and assigned.

Not sure what I am missing.

here are the pictures.

In rendered viewport:
[image]

Below is in material viewport:
[image]

This is how it's apparently supposed to look:
[image]

Help a brother out please.
Here is a blend file:
[image]

Comment: At first glance, I feel the problem is with the wave texture which is a color output (yellow dot output) given as an input to displacement, which in your case is a vector (purple dot input).Please share your blend file so that I can take a look at it? You can do this by uploading the blend file on this site - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and copy + pasting the generated url here.

Comment: @Teja Sure thing, blend is in the end.

Comment: It shows up fine in mine.Try this out. Add a 'texture coordinates' node and try different options to give as an input to wave texture vector input.(violet dot). 'texture coordinates' node is in input section of add menu (shift +A)

Comment: Hmm, texture coordinates didn't help, unfortunately. It's weird that it works on your end. Maybe I should try it on my other PC later on.

Comment: You're using Blender version 2.79.6 which now handles Displacement as a *vector* while the screenshot of how it should work is presumably 2.79b or earlier where it is a scalar. As a minimum should need to add a Displacement node (in the Vector menu) to translate your wave texture into a displacement along the surface normal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are using "True Displacement" (Geometry-> "Displacement Only" under settings in the Texture Panel) and your plane has no geometry to it whatsoever.

You can't use actual displacement when you have virtually no vertices to displace. All you have at the moment are the 4 verts that are the corners of your plane. Unless you add more geometry, you can only use the "fake" displacement created by a bump or normal map.

Subdivide your plane a few times (or add a subdivision surface modifier) and you will see the displacement in Rendered mode.

If you are trying to use Microdisplacements (??), then you need to enable the Experimental feature set under the Render Panel and then add an adaptive subsurface modifier to your object. That will also work, but might not be what you are trying to do.

Both are ways of getting more geometry to actually be displaced by your displacement texture.

Just to note - I believe the view you see in Texture mode is a bit misleading. I think that is using a bump map as a kind of preview, and not honoring the settings that apply at render time.

Comment: I see your point of view about displacement, and I have tried to add a couple subdivisions, as well as a hundred. I am afraid I didn't work. Check out this 1 minute youtube video, he basically has a similar plane and made it work somehow:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZGdYr_CdJ0

Comment: @Boyka I think that's just working as a bump map. He never moves the camera from looking directly down (which is when you would see the greatest effect from a bump map - i.e. when it will look its best). He also never expands the "Settings" section of the Texture panel, but I would bet money that he has this set (which I think used to be the default) to bump mapping and not "Displacement Only" like you have it set in your file. Set yours to bump and put the camera in the same place and you will get the same results. Alternatively use the bump node instead of the displacement socket.